# Shopware 6 Cloud App - how to access values from config.xml fields in the SCSS file?

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-app

I have a question: how can i (easy) implement the functionality from this plugin documentation https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/storefront/add-scss-variables-via-subscriber in a (cloud) app? I want to access values from config.xml fields in the SCSS file. I would be reluctant to define this as inline CSS (how SwagCustomNotification does it).

In the documentation under https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/apps/configuration scss is not included. So it is not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access fields defined in `config.xml` in scss files of regular apps but you should be able to [setup a theme within your app](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/apps/storefront/apps-as-themes). In the `theme.json` you can then define [theme specific config fields](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/themes/theme-configuration). These fields should then become available as variables in your theme's scss files. You can find and change the config fields in the administration in the theme settings when assigning the theme to a sales channel.